# Find Myhill–Nerode equivalence classes of language $\{0^n1^n: n \in \mathbb{N}_0 \}$

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

I'm asked to find all equivalence classes of the language

$$L = \{0^n1^n: n \in \mathbb{N}_0 \}$$
where $\mathbb N_0$ is the set of natural numbers including $0$, i.e., $0, 1, 2, \cdots.$

We have the following definition:

$$(xR_Ly)\Leftrightarrow (\forall w\in \Sigma^* xw\in L \Leftrightarrow yw\in L)$$

As I understand, words $x$ and $y$ belongs to different equivalence classes if $\exists z \in \Sigma^*: xz \in L$ and $yz \notin L$ (and vice versa).

The language $L$ above is not regular so it has infinitely many equivalence classes under $R_L$. In order to differentiate between two classes, I was thinking about defining the equivalence relation in the following way:

$$xR_Ly = \text{"}x[n] = y[n] = 0\text{ and }x[n+1] = y[n+1] = 1\text{"}$$

with $x[k]$ I mean the $k$-th letter in $x$. Under this "approach", all equivalence classes are generated by taking $n$ to be any number $\in \mathbb{N}_0$.

Under my attempt I have the following questions:

In the definition, nothing is said about $x$ and $y$ in $(xR_Ly)$. Do I have to assume that those are two arbitrary words that **are already** in $L$? (If not, then my approach doesn't work).

For a fixed $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$ I think $\exists$ just one word in the class $C_n$. Then does it mean that the unique word in $C_n$ is only equivalent to itself?

I think I'm not even close to the answer, so would appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 2):

For string $s$, call a string $e$ an extender of $s$ (with respect to $L$) if $es$ in $L$.

$x$ and $y$ are in the same equivalence class iff (a string is an extender of $x$ iff it is an extender of $y$).

Let us describe some sets.

- Let $O_{k}=\{0^k\},  \ \text{ where } k \in \mathbb N_0$.
  For any string $s$ in $O_k$, string $e$ is an extender of $s$ iff $e=0^i1^{i+k}$ for some $i\in\mathbb N_0$.
- Let $L_{k}=\{0^{m+1+k}1^m1: m\in\mathbb N_0\},  \ \text{ where } k \in \mathbb N_0.$
  For any string $s$ in $L_k$, string $e$ is an extender of $s$ iff $e=1^{k}$.
- Let $R=\{x\in\Sigma^*: x\text{ is not in any }O_k\text{ or }L_k\}$, where $\Sigma\supseteq\{0,1\}$ is the alphabet.
  Note that any string that can be extended to a string in $L$ must be $0^i1^j$ for some $i\ge j\ge0$, i.e., must be in $O_k$ or $L_k$ for some $k$.
  Hence, for any string $s$ in $R$, there is no extender of $s$.

The description above shows that all (Myhill–Nerode) equivalence classes of $L$ in $\Sigma^*$ are $O_0,O_1, O_2,\cdots, L_0, L_1, L_2, \cdots$ and $R$.

---

> In the definition, nothing is said about $x$ and $y$ in $(xR_Ly)$. Do I have to assume that those are two arbitrary words that **are already** in $L$? (If not, then my approach doesn't work)

No, $x$ and $y$ may or may not be in $L$. Your approach doesn't work.

> For a fixed $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$ I think $\exists$ just one word in the class $C_n$. Then does it mean that the unique word in $C_n$ is only equivalent to itself?

I cannot find where $C_n$ is defined. If it means $O_n$ defined above, then it does have only one word, $0^n$. The unique word in $O_n$ is only equivalent to itself.